# Gnome Evolution Email - Saving my messages as a .PDF file issue

Tags: pdf, gsettings, evolution

I wanted to save some Emails with all the formatting, images, and attachments, just as they appear in Evolution. I know I can 'File > Back up Evolution Data...' but I want it so I don't have to connect to the internet (IMAP server).

I've tried following the advice here: https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-save-as-pdf.html.en

But when I click on the file name to select the destination, I can't go past the Username directory. What's even more absurd is that I can't find the **.PDF** anywhere in the Terminal!

I also tried entering the code:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution.mail drag-and-drop-save-file-format 'pdf'
```

I just get the message *No such schema “org.gnome.evolution.mail”*

Evolution was installed as flatpak through the Fedora Software Center.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like you're printing dialog has restricted access to your data. This doesn't happen to be running as a Snap or similar? (If you don't know, please tell us what distribution you're on and how you installed evolution)

Comment: And making a backup is better than printing emails to PDFs: the printout will just show a printed version of the email, and only the preview (if any) of the attachment. A proper backup will actually contain the original, offline!

Comment: https://files.catbox.moe/q0o4fd.png
Here is an image of the Software Manager. As you can see, it's 'registry.fedoraproject.org'

Comment: ah, flatpak, not a snap. Anyways, I don't really see why it makes sense to install something that is supposed to integrate so tightly into your user session manager as evolution via a flatpak. Instead of the "FLATPAK", install the "RPM" version. Does that help? (PS: obviously, make a backup of the evolution data before you do that!)

Comment: Yea, that fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Wrote an answer to conserve that knowledge for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems printing from a flatpak-containerized application doesn't seem to work with the appropriate privileges.

The easiest solution is to install the native (RPM) version of evolution instead.